# Is it safe to remove files in .Sent/cur directory of dovecot?

Tags: mail-server, dovecot

For unknown reasons the `.Sent/cur` folder of one of the users had grown up to 500 MB. Is it safe if I remove all the files of this directory? And why it had grown up so dramatically? Note, that this situation is happened just for one specific user, other users has in their `.Sent/cur` folder just some kilobytes of files.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The folder you're talking about is part of a [Maildir](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maildir) mail folder.  Each file under the `cur` subdirectory represents a message in the folder.

Removing the files should work, but you'd probably have a better idea of what you're deleting if you delete the messages via an IMAP email client.

Taking Thunderbird as an example, you can click the button to the right of the list column headers and pick `Size` to show the size of each message in the folder.  This should make it pretty easy for the user to determine which messages are taking up most of the space.